# Mysql Count user, status, and todays date

Tags: php, mysql

I have an issue were I am trying to get the count for the user xgrh with status as completed and the current date from column compDt. This code just leaves my count as integer 0 when I have one record data entered for today date 10/28/14.

```html
<tr>
<td style="width: 125px"><a href="xgrhCompleted.php" target="Frame">xgrh</a></td>
<td style="width: 125px" align="center"><a href="xgrhCompleted.php" target="Frame">
<?php 
$result = mysql_query("SELECT  COUNT(*) as cd FROM requests WHERE status='Completed'  AND compUser='xgrh' AND CompDt = 'Date_Time=CURdate()'");
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))  
{  
echo $row['cd'];  
} 
?>
</a></td>
</tr>
```

[image]

Comment: What data type is the column `CompletedDate`?

Comment: I have it setup as text and i use this to insert the data.<td>Completed Date</td>
<td style="width: 303px">
<input type="text" value ="<?php echo date("m/d/y",time());?>"name="compDt" style="width: 148px"></td>

Comment: I was thinking maybe this was an issue

Comment: good idea let me set it up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Except from your typo, CURDATE() function returns format 'YYYY-MM-DD'.
The date you are trying to match (10/28/14) has format 'MM/DD/YY'.

Your query should be

```
 SELECT  COUNT(*) as cd FROM requests 
 WHERE status='Completed' AND compUser='xgrh' 
 AND CompDt = date_format(curdate(), '%m/%d/%y');
```

Comment: $result = mysql_query ("SELECT  COUNT(*) as cd FROM requests WHERE status='Completed' AND compUser='xgrh' AND CompDt = date_format(curdate(), '%m/%d/%y'");

Comment: Maybe if you post an sql fiddle with your schema we could reproduce the problem to find a solution.

Comment: gonna take me a bit to figure out fiddle

Comment: might be faster than figuring out the actual problem on your own.

Comment: All set got it working thanks everyone for help. I think I may start studying more MySQL before posting questions

Answer (score 0):

Typo in your query:

```
... AND CompDt = 'Date_Time=CURdate()'
                 ^-------------------^
```

Doing `a = b =c` doesn't make much sense, but since you've quoted the indicated part, you're not comparing a date to a date. You're comparing a date against a string which ISN'T a valid date, causing your entire `where` to evaluate to a boolean false, and return a count of 0.

Comment: when I  take the quotes out now the data doesn't show up at all just blank box

Comment: yes, because then it'll be `compdt = date_time = curdate()` which is illegal sql.

Comment: is there a way to convert it maybe